# Get DataResourceField value of DayPilot Scheduler

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, daypilot, daypilot-scheduler

I want to get `DataResourceField` value, when Move event is triggered.Below is my DayPilot Code.

```
   <DayPilot:DayPilotScheduler ID="dplRoom" runat="server" HeaderFontSize="8pt"
                                        HeaderHeight="20" 
                                        DataStartField="BookStartDate" 
                                        DataEndField="BookEndDate"
                                        DataTextField="AppName" 
                                        DataValueField="BID" 
                                        DataResourceField="BedID"
                                        EventHeight="30" 
                                        RowMinHeight="30" 
                                        EventFontSize="11px" 
                                        CellDuration="1440" 
                                        BackColor="White"
                                        CssClass="grid" 
                                        DurationBarVisible="false" 
                                        EventClickHandling="select" 
                                        EventClickJavaScript=""
                                        FreeTimeClickJavaScript="" 
                                        HeightSpec="Max" 
                                        Height="570" 
                                        CellGroupBy="Month"
                                        OnTimeRangeSelected="dplRoom_TimeRangeSelected" 
                                        TimeRangeSelectedHandling="JavaScript"
                                        TimeRangeSelectedJavaScript="timeRangeSelected(start, end, resource)" 
                                        ShowToolTip="false"
                                        EventMoveHandling = "CallBack" 
                                        OnEventMove="dplRoom_EventMove"  >
```

OnEventMove :

```
  Protected Sub dplRoom_EventMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventMoveEventArgs)
    Response.Write(e.NewEnd + " " + e.NewStart + " " + e.Value + " " + e.Text)
  End Sub
```

How can i get `DataResourceField` value on `EventMove` Event.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataResourceField`  actually gets or sets the name of the column that contains the primary key.

Try `e.NewResource` to get `DataResourceField` Value.